# Makefile single recipe for multiple patterns

Tags: makefile

Is there a simple way to apply a single recipe to multiple pattern rules?

Consider this directory structure

```
|- src
|  - file1.cpp
|- test
|  - file2.cpp
|  - file3.cpp
|  - metrics
|    - file4.cpp
|    - file5.cpp
```

I would like to write a single pattern rule to compile all the .cpp files in the test directory.  Here is what I have right now:

```
$(OBJS)/%.o: test/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS)/%.o: test/metrics/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -I test -c $< -o $@

TEST_CPP := $(wildcard test/*.cpp) $(wildcard test/**/*.cpp)
TEST_OBJ :=  $(addprefix $(OBJS)/,$(notdir $(TEST_CPP:.cpp=.o)))

$(BIN)/testRunner: $(TEST_OBJ)
    @mkdir -p $(BIN)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

I would like to avoid repeating the recipe for the object files.  I imagine the solution would look something like this:

```
$(OBJS)/%.o: test/%.cpp
$(OBJS)/%.o: test/metrics/%.cpp 
    @mkdir -p $(OBJS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

(At the moment, the objs directory is flat; but, I don't have a problem duplicating the source directory structure if that simplifies the makefile.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want.  The closest you can get is to put the recipe into a variable and use that same variable in each recipe, like this:

```
define BUILD_O
        @mkdir -p $(OBJS)
        g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
endef

$(OBJS)/%.o : test/%.cpp
        $(BUILD_O)
$(OBJS)/%.o : test/metrics/%.cpp
        $(BUILD_O)
```

As an alternative to that, because you want all your objects to go into the same directory but find sources from different directories, you could use VPATH instead and write just a single pattern rule, like this:

```
VPATH = test test/metrics

$(OBJS)/%.o : %.cpp
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I strongly urge you to rework your makefiles to use the standard variable names, though; use `$(CXX)`, not `g++`, for the C++ compiler name and `$(CXXFLAGS)`, not `$(FLAGS)`, for the C++ compiler options.

**EDIT**

If you need to customize flags, then the normal way to do this is either through [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), or through [constructed macro names](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/)

Target-specific variables would look like this:

```
test: $(test_targets)
test: FLAGS += -Dtest

production: $(production_targets)
production: FLAGS += -Dproduction
```

then when you run `make test` you'll get the `-Dtest` added; when you run `make production` you'll get the `-Dproduction` added.  There are issues here though: if you run `make myfoo.o` then you won't get these added (see the documentation).

Constructed macro names would look like this:

```
test_FLAGS = -Dtest
production_FLAGS = -Dproduction

rootdir = $(firstword $(subst /, ,$1))

VPATH = test test/metrics production production/widgets

$(OBJS)/%.o : %.cpp
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        g++ $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $($(call rootdir,$(<D))_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply VPATH only to certain rules?  Let's say I want a different flags/libraries/includes for the "test" .o files than for the "product" .o files.  I could set up separate pattern rules for `$(OBJS)/test/%.o` and `$(OBJS)/production/%.o`; but, then is there a way to limit pattern matches for .o files in `$(OBJS)/test` to sources in `/test`?

Comment: `VPATH` is global, but you could use the `vpath` directive like `vpath $(OBJS)/test/%.o test` (and likewise for production).

Comment: You can't use `vpath` like that: the pattern in `vpath` applies to the list of names you're looking for not the list of targets.  In other words your example tells make that it should look for .o files in `test`, not `.cpp` files.